# How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit in TCL?

Tags: tcl

In `TCL scripting`, how does one carry out these steps in reliable way?

1. **Set bit ​`n` in `x` to `'1'`**
2. **Clear bit ​n in `x` to `'0'`**
3. **Toggle bit `n` in `x`**
4. **Extract bit `n` in `x` only**
5. **Change bit `n` in `x` to value `y`**

The `TCl` reliance of `expr` makes mathematics of any type a bit confusing.

Comment: Can you not use the bitwise operators like any other arithmetic operator?

Comment: There is no example of the solution to the question on the Internet for TCL. I wonder who decided to downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but once you know that these are called bitwise operations, then it's pretty easy to find what you're looking for online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about toggling a single bit in a value encoded as an integer, it's easy. These are all the classic ways of doing bit manipulation (and you'd do something pretty much equivalent in lots of other languages too):

```
proc setBit {var bit} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    # OR
    set v [expr {$v | (1 << $bit)}]
}
proc clearBit {var bit} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    # AND NOT
    set v [expr {$v & ~(1 << $bit)}]
}
proc toggleBit {var bit} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    # XOR
    set v [expr {$v ^ (1 << $bit)}]
}
proc testBit {var bit} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    # select with AND and test
    return [expr {($v & (1 << $bit)) != 0}]
}
proc setBitTo {var bit value} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    set v [expr {$value ? $v | (1 << $bit) : $v & ~(1 << $bit)}]
}
```

Note that there's no maximum size of integers in current Tcl releases (storage is expanded to whatever space is needed). Things up to the size of a machine word are merely more efficient.

You can also use `binary scan` to convert chunks of data into strings of `0` and `1` and do string operations on that before using `binary format` to convert back, but it's actually more awkward.

Comment: No conversion rule caveats? Especially suspicious about the bitwise negations - how does tcl know (or how do I tell it) how many bits to negate?

Comment: So you are using curly braces so there is no need to using a lot of nested expr commands in [] ?

Comment: @quantum231 See https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr-essions

Comment: @Andreas Tcl knows that all bits that it doesn't have explicitly stored are either all 1 or all 0, and has a flag to store that; it's effectively the sign field of the representation used. The code's both careful and well tested; what others call nasty caveats and edge cases, we call implemented test cases.

Comment: *Note that there's no maximum size of integers in current Tcl releases (storage is expanded to whatever space is needed).* - Explain bignum bitwise negation. (Never encountered it before, or even given it any thought.)

Comment: @quantum231 The `expr` command can handle more than one operation.  No need to do anything like this:  `expr [expr 2+2] * [expr 3+3]`.      You can use parenthesese to change the order of operations:  `expr (2+2) * (3+3)`.   While it's not necessary, putting a pair of curlies around entire argument to `expr` is highly recommended.

Comment: Why is {} being used in the code above, can't it be written without using {} as well?